# DC Power supply

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, power-electronics

How can I make a 220 volt AC to DC power supply with a variable output voltage of 0-30 and a variable output current 0-5 with circuit protection?

Comment: This is way too broad, you are basically asking us to design for you a lab supply...

Comment: You don't. Power supplies with those exact specifications are readily available from a multitude of vendors for very low prices. Put your time and energy into a different project.

Comment: Even if you want to build one, the right place to search for it is GOOGLE.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to learn the design, then start breaking down the functional blocks and design each one out.

If your goal is to end up with a power supply like that, then I'd recommend buying one, as it will be much much cheaper than building your own.

Answer (score 0):

The "How" is a very vague question, and long to answer (it implies a lot of questions).

First understand and correct the question (making it more sensible and concrete), what is your main goal: current limiting and voltage regulation, current cutoff and voltage regulation, or how to make a psu in general...

Consider learning about ACDC DCDC converters in general by watching these videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWQvA_ZZEm66KT7lgJhtuof_2LybdNIfI

First video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbKwUSH9NiY&list=PLWQvA_ZZEm66KT7lgJhtuof_2LybdNIfI&index=2&t=0s&pbjreload=101
(in case the playlist link will break, you'll find them, they are numbered)

Comment: You don't need to add a comment to your own answer; you can just edit your answer as necessary. You might want to add some useful information to your answer. Answers that are just links to other sites are not very useful.